# The function will not pass anything to a SQL process, when called. There is no error

Tags: evil, sql-interactive-mode

I liked the interactivity of Clojure/Lisp, where you can see the result in the REPL. I tried to implement the same behaviour for SQL-mode.
The idea is that when I do <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> on the SQL-statemnt, I see the result in the `*SQL*`-mode, which will function as an alternative REPL.

To get this behaviour, I wrote two functions (I use Evil, so I have a normal, visual and insert state).

```
(defun sql-region-evaluate (start end)
"This will send the selected region to the SQL process"
(interactive "r")
(if (evil-visual-state-p)
    (sql-send-string (buffer-substring-no-properties start end))))
```

When I select a region, then I will use this function.

I do not want to use the `sql-send-buffer` command, because sometimes I type the next statement after the previous statement. When calling `sql-send-buffer` both SQL-statements will be queried, instead the last one.

So that's why I use the `sql-send-region`. The key command <kbd>vap</kbd> is an Evil keysequence in normal state which will visually selects the block.

```
(defun sql-evaluate (s)
"It will visually select the text block, and send it to the SQL process"
(interactive)
    ;; If I'm in the normal mode
    (if (evil-normal-state-p)
        (lambda ()
            (execute-kbd-macro (kbd "vap"))
            (sql-send-region start end)
            )))
```

When I call `sql-region-evaluate`, it works fine.
When I call `sql-evaluate`, nothing happens, I don't get any error message or something. So I cannot trace it back where it went wrong.

Any suggestions where it could get wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not doing what you think it is doing.  The latter example wraps two forms in a lambda, so all that happens is that `sql-evaluate` is going to return an anonymous function (or `nil` if you're not in visual state).

Please don't do that.  Use either `progn` for wrapping forms to be evaluated sequentially (with the last form as return value) or use special forms using an implicit `progn`, such as `when` (which is like `if`, but doesn't have an else clause, so it does allow you to specify as many then clauses as you need).

---

And now, a rewritten variant of the above (untested):

```
(defun my-eval-sql ()
  (interactive)
  (cond
   ((evil-visual-state-p)
    (sql-send-region (region-beginning) (region-end)))
   ((evil-normal-state-p)
    (sql-send-region (beginning-of-thing 'paragraph) (end-of-thing 'paragraph)))
   (t (user-error "Not in visual or normal state"))))
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Why is using lambda considered as not a good practice? And you recommend me to use `when`, but in your example I see you're using `cond` (which is a good example, actually!), without further use of `progn`. Your code works well by the way, but I would like to understand the decisions to structure such a Elisp form.

Comment: `when`/`unless` are good if you need one clause, `if` for two clauses and `cond` for everything else.  As both of your commands were highly redundant, I decided to combine both cases and the error case, so that made three branches and therefore a `cond`.

Comment: Regarding `lambda`, you're using it for the wrong purpose.  It's not about it being bad practice (even if I do consider using a named function most of the time), it's about not being the right tool for sequencing statements.  If you were using a higher-order function, sure, use a `lambda`, but not for this please.